# SCCM: In Place upgrade Win 7to win 10 1903 License issue

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, sccm, osd

I was working on one task sequence for In Place Upgrade. Win 10 1709 to Win 10 1903 is working fine.

But Win 7 to Win 10 1903 is getting failed during Upgrade Operating System step.

I checked some of the links and added the KMS Client Keys (NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43) in upgrade operating system step.

Also added one step to run vbs script.

```
Cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43
```

But Task Sequence is getting failed at this step.

```
Error: 0xC004F050 The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is invalid
```

Command line `Cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43 returned 3221549136`

In my environment, we are using KMS and we don't have a Volume license.

Any advise how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft article
[KMS client setup keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kmsclientkeys)
lists this serial key as:

```
Windows 10 Enterprise   NPPR9-FWDCX-D2C8J-H872K-2YT43
```

This key might not be suitable for your Windows 7 version.

You might either use another and more appropriate key from
[the list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kmsclientkeys#windows-10-all-supported-semi-annual-channel-versions).

You could also use Microsoft's
[Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10),
which can be run in Windows 7 to automatically choose the best Windows version
to upgrade to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to upgrade it to Win 10 Enterprise thats why I used this key. Do you think i need to change it for Win 7.

Comment: You cannot set the Windows 10 serial before the upgrade, if that's what is happening, only afterward.